# Exportar me sale sin el nombre de las columnas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando exportar una tabla y me sale bien pero sin los headers. ¿Me podéis ayudar? Esto es lo que he hecho hasta ahora

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "select * from Ana.dbo.detalle_incidencias" queryout C:\prueba.csv -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Comment: No hay ninguna opción en bcp para que explorte los nombres de columnas. Tendrás que hacerlo manualmente

Answer (score 1):

Como te comentó @Pikoh bcp no tiene forma de exportar los nombres de los campos, sin embargo hay un "truco" que puede que te sirva y pasa por la idea de exportar por un lado los nombres de los campos y por el otro los datos en sí, luego se hace un "merge" de ambos archivos, en tu caso sería algo así:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Cabecera
SELECT  @SQL = 'BCP "DECLARE @colnames VARCHAR(max);SELECT @colnames = COALESCE(@colnames + '','', '''') + column_name from Ana.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=''detalle_incidencias''; select @colnames;" queryout c:\cabecera.csv -c -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql

-- Datos
SELECT @SQL  = 'bcp "select * from Ana.dbo.detalle_incidencias" queryout C:\datos.csv -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql

-- Merge de ambos archivos
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'copy /b "d:\cabecera.csv"+"d:\datos.csv" "d:\prueba.csv"'

-- Borramos archivos intermedios
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'del "c:\cabecera.csv"'
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'del "c:\datos.csv"'
```

La contra que tiene este método es el innecesario procesamiento adicional para copiar los dos archivos en uno, en algunos casos puede ser importante.